# Counting the number of tags in input XML file using talend

Tags: etl, talend

I am reading the data from XML file using tFileInputXML.Each row of data is present in the one element like `<data columnName="[value]"/>`. I want to count number of data tag in the XML using Talend tool. If there are more than one tag then only i want to proceed the operation of inserting to table.How can i achieve this is talend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tFileInputXML->tJavaRow->tHashOutput
In tJavaRow, add 1 to a global var for each row.
Now you can a subjub (onSubjobOk) with tJava->if->tOracleOutput (or other).
For the "if" the condition should look like (Integer)globalMap.get("yourVariable") > 1

Hope this helps
TRF